# Creating an array of keys from a key value pair array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, keyvaluepair

Originally I sorted a Dictionary which returned a key-value pair array and was trying to turn this into a Dictionary, when I was notified that a dictionary's order is random so therefore what I was doing is useless. I am trying to turn this key-value pair array into an array of just the keys and was wondering how to do it. Here is my code:

```
    let posts = ["post1" : 3, "post2" : 41, "post3" : 27]

    let sortedPS = posts.sorted { $1.1 < $0.1 }
```

`posts` is a Dictionary and `sortedPS` is of type `Array<(key: String, value: Int)>` and is a Key-Value Pair Array/Array of Tuples from what I can tell. `sortedPS` should be an array of tuples which looks like this:

```
    ["post2" : 41, "post3" : 27, "post1" : 3]
```

I want an array out of this which should look like this:

```
    ["post2", "post3", "post1"]
```

Please let me know how I can take the keys from `sortedPS` and produce an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below short code to get all the keys from dictionary.

```
let posts = ["post1" : 3, "post2" : 41, "post3" : 27]

let sortedPS = posts.sorted { $1.1 < $0.1 }

let keys = sortedPS.map { $0.key } // ["post2", "post3", "post1"]
```

Comment: Gives 2 errors saying:  "anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has explicit arguments" and "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '((key: String, value: Int)) throws -> _'"

Comment: Please check my updated code, and confirm you following this

Comment: Works now, looks like I was using parentheses rather than brackets. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Short way:**

```
print(Array(posts.keys))
print(Array(posts.values))
Result:
["post2", "post3", "post1"]
```